# Create a new dataframe from others dataframes using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have these 3 dataframes:

```
    df.1<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10),250,149))
    df.2<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10),250,149))
    df.3<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10),250,149))
```

I want to create another dataframe with these conditions:

```
the columns 1,4,7,10,...445 of df.4... will be the columns from df.1

the columns 2,5,8,11,...446 of df.4... will be the columns from df.2

the columns 3,6,9,12,...447 of df.4... will be the columns from df.3
```

In the ende my df.4 will have `3*149` columns.

How can I do this with `dplyr` package and its functions?

**And most important**, how can I mantain the names of my columns???

Comment: Do you really need three `250x149` (!) matrices to make your example reproducible?

Comment: @MauritsEvers :) no. It can be a smaller one. Because my original matrix has this dimensions

Comment: @RonakShah I edited the question. In the end my df.4 will have `3*149 = 447` columns

Comment: @李哲源 Im truly sorry. It wont happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this we combine the dataframes with `bind_cols()` then reorder with `select()` as follows:

```
library (dplyr)
df.4 <- bind_cols(df.1, df.2, df.3)
# create the column order 
order <- c()
for(i in 1:149){
    temp <- c(i, i+149, i+298)
    order <- c(order, temp)
}
df.4 <- df.4 %>% select(order)
```

The loop used here is looping over numbers 1:149 and will not be slow regardless of the size of your data

Comment: Thanks @Abdallah Atef but its not working. The original dataframes df.1, df.2 and df.3 all have 149 columns

Comment: No. It would ok a loop